# Decoding JSON in Perl

Tags: json, perl, decoding

I have a JSON file like this one (it is a piece of the entire JSON file):

```
{
  id => "mgp1310",
  samples => [
    {
      envPackage => {
        data => {
          diss_carb_dioxide => {
            aliases    => ["sediment_diss_carb_dioxide"],
            definition => "concentration of dissolved carbon dioxide",
            mixs       => 1,
            required   => 0,
            type       => "text",
            unit       => "",
            value      => "17 mM",
          },
        },
        id => "mge64559",
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

This has been decoded by module JSON, using:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

open($fh, '<', 'hola.txt' );
$json_text   = <$fh>;
$perl = decode_json($json_text);
print Dumper($perl);
```

Now I know that `$perl` has a hash. So I'd like to print the `id` of the JSON file using `print $perl{"id"};`. However, it prints nothing I don't know why.

Comment: `use strict;` and try again.

Comment: Never something so simple was so useful...

Comment: `use warnings;` is real useful too.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer by adding `use strict` at my code. It threw the following error:

```
Global symbol "%perl" requires explicit package name at json.pl line 12.
```

The variable `$perl` is a scalar, not a hash!. Of course... I didn't thought about that. So I cannot access to the hash writing `$perl{"id"}`. The correct way is `$perl->{id}`.